# Iterating elements using NightWatchJS

Tags: automation, nightwatch.js

How do i click a button returned by elements command in night watch

```
client.elements('xpath', ".//a[@class='abcd')]", function (allButtons){
        console.log('Element value is '+element)
        allButtons.value.forEach(function (element) {
            this.elementIdClick(element, function(res){});
    }
}
```

While running i am getting an error as

> Element value is [object Object]
>
> ```
> TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'elementIdClick'
> ```

So how do i get each element from the element list returned by `client.elements`

I realized the parameters for elementIdClick is wrong, i updated the code as

```
client.elements('xpath', ".//a[@class='abcd')]", function (allButtons){

allButtons.value.forEach(function (element) {
    console.log('Element value is '+element)
    this.elementIdClick(this.elementIdAttribute(allButtons.value[element].ELEMENT, 'id'), function(res){});
```

Now the error is

```
Element value is [object Object]
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'ELEMENT' of undefined
```

So again back to original question. How do i get individual elements from a list of webelements using nightwatchJS

Comment: what is problem here

Comment: Sorry, question updated

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me:

```
function iter(elems) {
    elems.value.forEach(function(element) {
        client.elementIdClick(element.ELEMENT)
    })
};
client.elements('css selector', 'button.my-button.to-iterate', iter);
```

- Each `element` is a *JSON* object of the form `{ ELEMENT: string }` (so, has no method itself.)
- `this` in `forEach` does *not* point to the `element`, nor `client`: you need to invoke `client.elementIdClick()` or will get a `TypeError`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No success using this. I am getting an error something like this TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined
Not sure if there is need to install something else to use selenium protocols.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following strategy to iterate over DOM elements using Nightwatch:

```
// Executing a function in the application context.
client.execute(function () {

  // Get elements by CSS selector.
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.elements');

  // Iterate over them.
  [].forEach.call(elements, function (element) {

    // Manipulate each element.
    element.click();
  });
});
```

That snippet is inside a test of course.

If you use jQuery or something similar you can use that too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is getting generated by your console.log() statement.

From the elements() command, `allButtons.value` will be an **array** of several objects.  To access key pairs in that array, you need need to specify where in the array and then reference the object: `allButtons.value[index].ELEMENT`

Because you gave your `.forEach()` loop only one arg, it's interpreting that as the `index` for the `array`, and in my code sample below I replaced your local variable `element` with `index` for clarity.  There is also no need to use the .elementIdAttribute() function; the number returned by `allButtons.value[0].ELEMENT` will work as the id.

```
client.elements('xpath', ".//a[@class='abcd')]", function (allButtons){

    allButtons.value.forEach(function (index) {
    console.log('Element value is '+index.ELEMENT)
    client.elementIdClick(index.ELEMENT);}})
```

Hope that helps.